# How to specify frame rate ourselves while using mmreader in matlab

Tags: matlab, video

I am having a video in matlab; I read that using mmreader. The file information is:

Video Settings:

```
BitsPerPixel = 24
FrameRate = 25
Height = 288
NumberOfFrames = 590
VideoFormat = RGB24
Width = 352
```

In my coding I want to change the frame rate to a certain value. How can I do this?

Comment: I am getting no logic how to achieve this.

Comment: Can I use set command for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
movie(M,n,fps)
```

This plays the movie at fps frames per second. The default is 12 frames per second. Computers that cannot achieve the specified speed play as fast as possible

Or, see for example this code bit (taken from matlab documentation). Especially the LAST line of it...

```
%Read and play back the movie file xylophone.mpg:
xyloObj = mmreader('xylophone.mpg');

nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;
vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;

% Preallocate movie structure.
mov(1:nFrames) = ...
struct('cdata', zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3, 'uint8'),...
       'colormap', []);

% Read one frame at a time.
for k = 1 : nFrames
   mov(k).cdata = read(xyloObj, k);
end

% Size a figure based on the video's width and height.
hf = figure;
set(hf, 'position', [150 150 vidWidth vidHeight])

 % Play back the movie once at the video's frame rate.
 movie(hf, mov, 1, xyloObj.FrameRate);
```

Comment: I don't think so that I can use the above code because I don't want to play the movie at video's frame rate. I want to specify frame rate property myself. In the command movie(M,n,fps) ; what parameter M stands for? I have read the documentation but still its not clear to me.

Comment: M is the movie, n is the number of repeats to show it, fps is what the frames pre second you want it to play, you can write any number you want. for example: 'movie(M,1,5)' will show the movie once at 5 fps. I think you should try to read matlab's documentation. just write 'doc movie' and see.

Comment: I have read that but I am not getting how to define M. I should simply assign my movie to it? what is the exact syntax which I should use.

Comment: you stated you "have a video in Matlab", how is it called then?

Comment: Sir I have read the video using mmreader; using the statement:                           myvid=mmreader('myownvideo.avi')                                         What do you mean by how is it called then?

Comment: movie(M) plays the movie in matrix M once; this is the exact line written in the matlab documentation. Its not clear to me rather I am having no idea how to use it.

Comment: All you need to do is to use the code bit I wrote in my answer. Just replace the first line 'xyloObj = mmreader('xylophone.mpg');' with this one 'xyloObj = mmreader('myownvideo.avi');' and the last line with 'movie(hf, mov, 1, 14);'. Here I selected 14 fps, but you can put any number you want instead of the 14.

Comment: ok thank you sir now I got it and its working perfectly. please Sir clear one thing more to me; as I have told you earlier that the original video has frame rate=25 and I have changed its value; suppose its 60 using the above procedure. Now I want to read the movie having frame rate 60 rather than 25 using mmreader; how can I do that.

Comment: Sir I am having matlab-2009 and this feature is not available in it. I think I should first install matlab-2012 and then try it. Thank you for the guidance. I will let you know if I will be having some issue.